# Sendgrid: how to use different tracking settings for different sets of messages

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

My application needs to send some messages with tracking activated and other messages without tracking.

When using Sendgrid, many settings, among them tracking settings, can be set using the admin web interface, and these settings will be used for all subsequent messages sent.

But is it possible to have different settings for different sets (or categories ?) of messages, and have the application define which settings to use when sending a given message through API ?

Or maybe define the tracking settings as part of the send API parameters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When sending [via the v3 API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html), there's a `tracking_settings` field, where you can dynamically enable/disable settings for just that message.

There's a [similar option](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/apps.html) when using the SMTPAPI JSON header.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem. 
After some investigation found two satisfactory solutions.
The fist one - integrate with google analytic.
The second - we moved all dynamic templates into application (also due to sg limitation for dynamic content) and added specific utm tags (UTM_SOURCE, UTM_CONTENT, UTM_MEDIUM, UTM_CAMPAIGN, UTM_TERM;) to each letter. And after user click on emails content FE process this tags.